Can't launch Android Studio emulators with Flutter: Launch emulator inside Visual Studio Code
What I am trying to do
I'm trying to launch an emulator from Android Studio directly from VS Code using > Flutter: Launch Emulator. When I'm running the command, it shows no emulator. What I'm expecting is to see a list of three emulators that I currently have on Android Studio. I would then be able to launch one of them.
Initial cause of the issue
I've moved my Android Studio's files to my D: Drive inside D:\Android_Studio_Data. To try to make everything work, I've set the user environment variables ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_USER_HOME and I've added /platform-tools, /tools and /tools/bin to my user path variable.
Tree representation of my folder
What I have tried
I've disabled and re-enabled the Flutter and Dart extension on flutter and restarted my PC after I've modified the paths.
Running flutter doctor -v shows everything as successful.
Running emulator -list-avds returns nothing.
Running D:\Android_Studio_Data\SDK\emulator\emulator.exe -list-avds returns
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\math2\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 55248
Since running flutter devices (which also returns no emulator) executes a command from  D:\Android_Studio_Data\SDK\emulator\emulator.exe, I think the issue must come from the emulator.exe. I think it's supposed to be able to list my avd, but it doesn't.
Would anyone know why running emulator.exe -list-avds returns none of my AVD that I have on Android Studio?
